# Dice Battle Game

Tags: vb.net

I need help with a dice battle game for Visual Basic.

A player and a computer are supposed to battle each other. When you click on the **Roll** button, it generates 6 random images - 3 for the PC and 3 for the PLAYER.

I got everything down, but I can't seem to add the 3 images. The first image shows, but the second and third aren't showing up, nor the three for the PC.

Here is my code

```
//=============================================================================
Public Class Form1

Dim randomObject As New Random() 'Create Random object
Dim BestOfGamesCounter As Integer

Private Sub RollDice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RollDice.Click
    If GameTextBox.Text <= "0" Then
        MsgBox("Number of Games > 0", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Application.Restart()
    End If

    If GameTextBox.Text > "0" Then
        BestOfGamesCounter = Convert.ToInt32(GameTextBox.Text)
    End If


    DisplayDie(d1PictureBox)
    DisplayDie(d2PictureBox)
    DisplayDie(d3PictureBox)

    DisplayDie(UserDice1)
    DisplayDie(UserDice2)
    DisplayDie(UserDice3)
End Sub

Sub DisplayDie(diePictureBox As PictureBox)
    'generate random integer in range 1 to 6
    Dim face As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 7)

    'retrieve specific die image from resources
    Dim pictureResource = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("die{0}", face))

    'Convert pictureResource to type Image and display in ImageBox
    diePictureBox.Image = CType(pictureResource, Image)
End Sub ' DisplaDie

Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    Dim response As MsgBoxResult
    response = MsgBox("Do you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question)
    If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Me.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GameTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles GameTextBox.Validating
    If GameTextBox.Text > "0" Then
        Do
            MsgBox(GameTextBox.Text + " round(s) will be played GOOD LUCK")
        Loop While GameTextBox.Text = "STOP"
    End If
    GameTextBox.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Your code is VB.Net, not VBA.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: By the way, you can load the images like this: `diePictureBox.Image = New Bitmap(Me.GetType, "die" & face)`

Comment: Oh ok thank you for that knowledge. And no I just cant seem to add the dices Im just having issues I don't know if I have to convert each individual image to an integer so seven images will equal 1 - 6 integers because a dice has up to 6 faces. for example if the 3 dices that are being rolled end up being 1 ill add them to make it equal 3 suppose that the random generated it

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to help much just by looking at the code.  Are you sure the names of the resources are correct?  How about the layout of the PictureBoxes?  Maybe some screenshots to show us the layout of the form and the resources as they are listed in your project?

Comment: Thank you guys anyways I was able to figure it out.